# Improve speed of query in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, database, indexing, sqlalchemy, clustered-index

In an attempt to teach myself how to program, I'm making a web app (Flask, SQLAlchemy, Jijna) to display all the books I've ever ordered from Amazon.

In the "barest bones" possible way, I'm trying to learn how to replicate http://pinboard.in—that's my paragon. I have no idea how his site runs so fast: I can load 160 bookmark entries—*all with associated tags*—in, I dunno, 500 ms? ... which is why I know I am doing something wrong, as discussed below.

In any case, I created a many-to-many relationship between my `books` Class and my `tag` Class such that a user can (1) click on a `book` and see all its `tags`, as well as (2) click on a `tag` and see all associated books. Here is my table architecture:

[Entity relationship diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOUAN.png)

Here is the code for the relationship between the two Classes:

```py
assoc = db.Table('assoc',
    db.Column('book_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('books.book_id')),
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tags.tag_id'))
)

class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'books'
    book_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    auth = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    comment = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    date_read = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    era = db.Column(db.String(36))
    url = db.Column(db.String(120))
    notable = db.Column(db.String(1))

    tagged = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=assoc, backref=db.backref('thebooks',lazy='dynamic'))

    def __init__(self, title, auth, comment, date_read, url, notable):
        self.title = title
        self.auth = auth
        self.comment = comment
        self.date_read = date_read
        self.era = era
        self.url = url
        self.notable = notable
    
class Tag(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'
    tag_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag_name = db.Column(db.String(120))
```

## the problem

If I iterate through the `books` table only (~400 rows), the query runs and renders to the browser in lightning speed. No problem there.

```html
{% for i in book_query %}
    <li>
      {{i.notable}}{{i.notable}}
      <a href="{{i.url}}">{{i.title}}</a>, {{i.auth}}
      <a href="/era/{{i.era}}">{{i.era}}</a> {{i.date_read}}
        {% if i.comment %}
          <p>{{i.comment}}</p>
        {% else %}
          <!-- print nothing -->
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

If, however, I want to show any and all tags associated with a book, I change the code by nesting a `for loop` as follows:

```html
{% for i in book_query %}
    <li>
      {{i.notable}}{{i.notable}}
      <a href="{{i.url}}">{{i.title}}</a>, {{i.auth}}
      <a href="/era/{{i.era}}">{{i.era}}</a>
        {% for ii in i.tagged %}
            <a href="/tag/{{ii.tag_name}}">{{ii.tag_name}}</a>
        {% endfor %}
      {{i.date_read}}
        {% if i.comment %}
          <p>{{i.comment}}</p>
        {% else %}
          <!-- print nothing -->
        {% endif %}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
```

The query *slows down significantly* (takes about 20 seconds). My understanding is that this is happening because for every row in the `book` table, my code is iterating through *the entire* `assoc` table (i.e., "full table scan").

## discussion (or, "what i think is happening")

Obviously, I am a complete noob—I've been programming for ~3 months. It's motivating just to get things working, but I realize I have large gaps in my knowledge base that I am trying to fill as I go along.

Right off that bat, I can appreciate that it's incredibly inefficient that, with each new book, the code is iterating through the *entire association table* (if that's indeed what's happening, which I believe it is). I think I need to cluster(?) or sort(?) the `assoc` table in such a way that once I retrieve all tags for `book with book_id == 1`, I never again "check" the rows with `book_id == 1` in the `assoc` table.

In other words, what I think is happening is this (in computerspeak):

- Oh, he wants to know how the book with `book_id == 1` in `books` table has been tagged
- Okay, let me go to the `assoc` table
- Row #1 ... Is `book_id` in `assoc` table equal to `1`?
- Okay, it is; then what is the `tag_id` for Row #1? ... [then computer goes to `tag` table to get `tag_name`, and returns it to the browser]
- Row #2 ... is `book_id` in `assoc` table equal to `1`?
- Oh, no, it isn't ... okay, go to Row #3
- Hmmmm, because my programmer is stupid and didn't make this table sorted or indexed in some way, I'm going to have to go through the entire `assoc` table looking for `book_id == 1` when perhaps there aren't any more ...

Then, once we get to `book_id == 2` in the `books table` the computer gets really mad:

- Okay, he wants to know all the tags that go with `book_id == 2`
- Okay, let me go to the `assoc` table
- Row #1 ... wait a second ... didn't I check this one already?? Holy sh#t, I have to do this all over again??
- Dammit ... okay ... Row #1 ... is `book_id == 2`? (I know it isn't! But I have to check anyway because my programmer is a dum-dum ...)

## questions

So the question is, can I (1) sort(?) or cluster(?) the `assoc` table in some way that ensures more "intelligent" traversal through the `assoc` table, or, as a friend of mine suggested, do I (2) "learn to write good SQL queries"? (Note, I've never learned SQL since I've been handling everything with SQLAlchemy ... damn Alchemists ... enshrouding their magics in secret and whatnot.)

## final words

Thanks for any input. If you have any suggestions to help me improve how I ask questions on stackoverflow (this is my first post!) please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the answer is in the question.

In the first example 1 SQL query is executed when you iterate through `books` table. In the second example a separate `assoc` query is executed for every `Book`. So it is about 400 SQL queries which are quite time consuming. You can view them in your app debug log if you set [SQLALCHEMY_ECHO](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/config/) config parameter:

```py
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
```

Or you can install [Flask-DebugToolbar](https://flask-debugtoolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and look at these queries in web interface.

The best approach to handle this problem is to learn SQL basics, you will need them anyway when your applications grow larger. Try to write a more optimized query in pure SQL. For your case it may look like this:

```sql
SELECT books.*, tags.tag_name FROM books
JOIN assoc ON assoc.book_id = books.book_id
JOIN tags ON assoc.tag_id = tags.tag_id
```

Then try to rewrite it in SQLAlchemy code and then group by book before passing to HTML renderer:

```py
# Single query to get all books and their tags
query = db.session.query(Book, Tag.tag_name).join('tagged')
# Dictionary of data to be passed to renderer
books = {}
for book, tag_name in query:
    book_data = books.setdefault(book.book_id, {'book': book, 'tags': []})
    book_data['tags'].append(tag_name)
# Rendering HTML
return render_template('yourtemplate.html', books=books)
```

Template code will look like this:

```html
{% for book in books %}
<li>
  {{ book.book.notable }}{{ book.book.notable }}
  <a href="{{ book.book.url }}">{{ book.book.title }}</a>, {{ book.book.auth }}
  <a href="/era/{{ book.book.era }}">{{ book.book.era }}</a>
  {% for tag in book.tags %}
    &nbsp;<a href="/tag/{{ tag }}" class="tag-link">{{ tag }}</a>&nbsp;
  {% endfor %}
  {{ book.book.date_read }}
    {% if book.book.comment %}
      <p>{{ book.book.comment }}</p>
    {% else %}
      <!-- print nothing -->
    {% endif %}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

**Another approach**

If your database is PostgreSQL you can write such query:

```sql
SELECT books.title, books.auth (...), array_agg(tags.tag_name) as book_tags FROM books
JOIN assoc ON assoc.book_id = books.book_id
JOIN tags ON assoc.tag_id = tags.tag_id
GROUP BY books.title, books.auth (...)
```

In this case you will get books data with already aggregated tags as an array. SQLAlchemy allows you to make such query:

```py
from sqlalchemy import func

books = db.session.query(Book, func.array_agg(Tag.tag_name)).\
    join('tagged').group_by(Book).all()
return render_template('yourtemplate.html', books=books)
```

And template has the following structure:

```html
{% for book, tags in books %}
<li>
  {{ book.notable }}{{ book.notable }}
  <a href="{{ book.url }}">{{ book.title }}</a>, {{ book.auth }}
  <a href="/era/{{ book.era }}">{{ book.era }}</a>
  {% for tag in tags %}
    &nbsp;<a href="/tag/{{ tag }}" class="tag-link">{{ tag }}</a>&nbsp;
  {% endfor %}
  {{ book.date_read }}
    {% if book.comment %}
      <p>{{ book.comment }}</p>
    {% else %}
      <!-- print nothing -->
    {% endif %}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I wanted to include books that did not have any tags yet. I was able to get all books, with or without tags, but using 'outerjoin' instead of 'join'.

Answer (score 1):

The following implementation, adapted from @Sergey-Shubin, was a workable solution to this question:

## classes & table association declaration

```py
assoc = db.Table('assoc',
    db.Column('book_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('books.book_id')),
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tags.tag_id'))
    )

class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'books'
    book_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    auth = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    comment = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    date_read = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    era = db.Column(db.String(36))
    url = db.Column(db.String(120))
    notable = db.Column(db.String(1))    

    tagged = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=assoc, backref=db.backref('thebooks',lazy='dynamic'))

class Tag(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'
    tag_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag_name = db.Column(db.String(120))

def construct_dict(query):
        books_dict = {}
        for each in query: # query is {<Book object>, <Tag object>} in the style of assoc table - therefore, must make a dictionary bc of the multiple tags per Book object
            book_data = books_dict.setdefault(each[0].book_id, {'bookkey':each[0], 'tagkey':[]}) # query is a list of like this {index-book_id, {<Book object>}, {<Tag object #1>, <Tag object #2>, ... }}
            book_data['tagkey'].append(each[1])
        return books_dict
```

## route, sql-alchemy query

```py
@app.route('/query')
def query():
    query = db.session.query(Book, Tag).outerjoin('tagged') # query to get all books and their tags
    books_dict = construct_dict(query)

    return render_template("query.html", query=query, books_dict=books_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your query has a lot of books, fetching the tags for each book one by one in a separate SQL statement will kill your response time in network I/O.

One way to optimize that, if you know you always will need the tags for this query, is to hint SQLAlchemy to fetch all the dependent tags in one query either via join or subquery.

I don't see your query, but my guess is a subquery load would work best for your use case:

```
session.query(Book).options(subqueryload('tagged')).filter(...).all()
```